# How to point-by-point animate disjoined lines using matplotlib.animation (python)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

**Summary**:

- Objective: Animate plotting of disjointed lines(where each line is an array of x,y pair).
- Problem: I can't find a way to make each line disjointed from each other.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from itertools import count

stroke = [[1,2,0], [2,1,0], [3,2,1], [5,2,0], [6,1,0], [7,2,1], [9,2,0],
           [10,1,0], [11,2,1]]
stroke = np.asarray(stroke)

X = []
Y = []
for x,y,br in stroke:
    if br != 1:
        X.append(x)
        Y.append(y)
    else:
        X.append(x)
        Y.append(y)
        plt.plot(X,Y, c='k')
        X = []
        Y = []

plt.show()
```

[image]

When I am trying to animate this plot I am ending up with
[image]

```py
# ANIMATION CODE SNIPPET

stroke_len = len(stroke)
X_data = list()
Y_data = list()
idx_counter = count()


def animation_frame(i):
    global X_data, Y_data, idx_counter
    print(i)
    idx = next(idx_counter)

    if idx == stroke.shape[0]-1:
        idx_counter = count()

    if i != 1 :
        X_data.append(stroke[idx, 0])
        Y_data.append(stroke[idx, 1])
    else:
        X_data.append(stroke[idx, 0])
        Y_data.append(stroke[idx, 1])
        X_data = []
        Y_data = []
    

    plt.plot(X_data, Y_data, c='k')


animation = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), func=animation_frame,
                          frames=stroke[:, 2], interval=500)

# plt.show()

animation.save('anim.mp4')
```

Also it is appreciated if you could suggest any other library where I can achieve similar goal.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to workaround this problem by inserting `None` wherever I need a break point in the plot.

I made the following changes in the `animation_frame` function.

```py
# ANIMATION CODE SNIPPET

stroke_len = len(stroke)
X_data = list()
Y_data = list()
idx_counter = count()

def animation_frame(i):
    global X_data, Y_data, idx_counter
    print(i)
    idx = next(idx_counter)

    if idx == stroke.shape[0]-1:
        idx_counter = count()

    if i != 1 :
        X_data.append(stroke[idx, 0])
        Y_data.append(stroke[idx, 1])
    else:
        X_data.extend([None, stroke[idx, 0]]) # Changes Here
        Y_data.extend([None, stroke[idx, 1]]) # Changes Here

    

    plt.plot(X_data, Y_data, c='k')


animation = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), func=animation_frame,
                          frames=stroke[:, 2], interval=500)

# plt.show()

animation.save('anim.mp4')
```

[image: animation]

Hope this helps you too.

Comment: This code snippet doesn't work in Jupyter. I get a black box.